# Automatic reminder via email python

Tags: python

I was reading about automating the boring stuff with python, and I was trying to thing of my own programs I can make and I had the idea of emailing myself every morning a list of things I have to finish today, that way I can get a notification reminder every morning.

How would I go about this. I understand python and can use it but i don’t know much about smtp module assuming that is what I would be using

I want it to be super simple just a text file and every morning the contents of whatever is written in that file to be sent to my gmail so I can get a notification on my phone

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example)

Answer (score 0):

The smtp module is probably what you want to use ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html ):

There's also more powerful packages, but for small things this should be sufficient

A very simplistic example to send a mail:

If you want this to happen every morning, then I would use crontabs ore windows scheduled tasks to schedule your script

```
import smtplib

SERVERNAME = 'localhost'
SENDER = "your@mail.com"
RECIPIENTS = ["your@mail.com"]
FILE_TO_SEND = "myfilename"
USER = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"

def sendmail():
    with open(FILE_TO_SEND) as fin:
        msg = fin.read()

    server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    server.starttls()  # if you're using TLS if no encryption, then 
                       # comment this line
    server.login(USER, PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENTS, msg)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, looks easy to understand! I have to wait until after skl to give it a go tho.